# Unable to use StackNavigator in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a simple navigation in the following page:

**Page1:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

var styles = require('./styles');


class Page1 extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

componentDidMount() {      // <== Edited
   setTimeout(function() { 
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    },4000);
 }
  render() {

      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;  // <= Getting error here

      const { fname, lname } = this.props.person;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          From Page 1 - {lname} { fname}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          // onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2', { user: 'Lucy' }) }
        >
        <Text style={styles.welcome}> click for Page 2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    person:state.person
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps) (Page1);
```

**Page 3:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import Page1 from './Page1'

import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './store'

const store = configureStore()

export default class Page3 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Page1 /> 
      </Provider>     
    );
  }
}
```

And in the index page I'm importing Page1, Page2 and Page3 and :

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Page1: { screen: Page1 },
  Page2: { screen: Page2 },
  Page3: { screen: Page3 },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('my03', () => SimpleApp);
```

The app works fine unless I comment `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`. I get the following error:

[image]

Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

I also tried: 
`onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2', { user: 'Lucy' }) }` and 
`onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Page2', { user: 'Lucy' }) }`

Not really sure why I tried it but was going to figure it out if it worked. It did not.

I'm trying to use [ReactNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) without creating the reducer for it, cause I did not understand [this part](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) even after trying for 2 days.

Why is this failing here? Please help.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE1**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Page1 from './src/components/Page1'
import Page2 from './src/components/Page2'
import Page3 from './src/components/Page3'

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Page3: { screen: Page3 },
  Page2: { screen: Page2 },
  Page1: { screen: Page1 },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('my03', () => SimpleApp);
```

Comment: Page1 is not added to the StackNavigator.

Comment: Added, re-pushed the app. Still exactly same issue.

Comment: Directly use navigate('Page2', { user: 'Lucy' })

Comment: @bennygenel .. I don't think `Redux` integration is even a problem here. But when I created a new project and used the navigation, it just works. For some reason `this.props.navigation` is not working in `Page1`. Am I right?

Comment: @DeepakSachdeva ..  You mean : `onPress={() => navigate('Page2', { user: 'Lucy' }) }` ? I did that and get `can't find variable navigate`

Comment: I think problem is that when the Component rendering the props not fully set so `this.props.navigation.navigate` gives an error. Try using the navigate on `comonentDidMount` with a `setTimeout` after commenting the line that gives an error. just to test it out

Comment: @bennygenel .. Edited `Page1` .. Please check if I did it right. But it fails with same error for the line `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: @Somename Why did you remove the "tick" from my answer? :(

Comment: @MustansirZia .. sorry .. was a mistake. Thanks a ton again for the detailed explanation. I understood a lot from it.

Comment: You're really welcome! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer. Just do this. `<Page1 navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Explanation - The reason why `this.props.navigation` is coming out undefined is that you're essentially using another instance of the `Page 1` component inside your `Page 3` and not the one that you used to initialize the `StackNavigator` with. So it's an entirely new `Page 1` that is not coupled with the StackNavigator at all.  If `Page 1` would have been the starting component of your `StackNavigator`. Then `this.props.navigation` would not have been undefined which brings me to another point of interest.

Why would you ever nest `Page 1` inside `Page 3` but want the same page as a sibling to `Page 3` inside your react navigation stack? The idea is to add components inside our `StackNavigator` as screens without nesting them together and we move from one screen to another using `this.props.navigation.navigate` inside any one of them. So, therefore, our `Page 3` would have our `navigation` prop (since I'm assuming it gets loaded first through the `StackNavigator` directly) we just pass that prop to our nested `Page 1` component and viola! You would now have access to `this.props.navigation` inside your `Page 1`.

Also, since your `Page 3` has the `<Provider >` tag I'm assuming it's something more of a root. In that case, you're better off using `<SimpleApp >` in place of `<Page1 >` and keeping `Page 1` as the starting point of your Stack. You can then register your root component as `AppRegistry.registerComponent('my03', () => Page3);`

The last piece of info, you can keep your redux state and your navigation completely decoupled from each other so use redux integration only when you're absolutely sure that you need your navigation state inside your redux store. A project which has both Redux and ReactNavigation doesn't mean that you have to integrate them both. They can be completely separate.

Phew! Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks a million. It worked. The reason I'm nesting `Page1` to `Page3` is I want to show some items from the `Redux` state in `Page1` and when I use `mapStateToProps` and `connect` it with `Page1`, I get error : `Could not find  store in either the context or props of "Connect(Page1)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Page1)"`. So am I right in assuming whenever I use `connect` I have to `<Provider>`? And how would I show other content of the `Page1` inside of `<Provider>`? many thanks

Comment: Also, if I want to show something from the state in `Page2`, I'll have to `connect` it with `MapStateToProps` as well and it gives the same error. How can I go about this?

Comment: Okay! Are you using `<SimpleApp />` inside your `<Provider />` or you're using `<Page1 />` still?

And. What do you mean by show other content of the `Page1` inside of `<Provider>`?

Comment: `SimpleApp` is defined in the index as I mentioned in the question. Not using it anywhere but only in `AppRegistry`. Whatever you see in `Page1` in `return( ListView, TouchableOpacity, Redux state items, etc. )` How will I show this content in `<Provider>`?

Comment: If I do `return(<Provider store={store}>  ListView, TouchableOpacity, Redux state items, etc. </Provider>)` this will not work, right? I don't understand how to have multiple pages that show `Redux` state content and how to `connect` them with `mapStateToProps` in this case. Hope I'm not confusing you. I'll explain more if you want please.

Comment: Alright, I think I understood you. What you do is,
 `<Provider store={store}>
        <SimpleApp /> 
      </Provider> `
Now just add `Page1` as the first screen of the stack navigator and remove `Page3` as now that's the root component of your app.
This way you can wrap `Provider` to all your screens (since it's wrapping `<SimpleApp />`) and thus `connect` would work inside all of them.
So the AppRegistery would now look like. `AppRegistry.registerComponent('my03', () => Page3);`

Comment: I'm sorry .. Do I do `<Provider store={store}> <SimpleApp /> </Provider>` in the index file? `Simpleapp` is the `StackNavigator` as I mentioned in my question. Should I import the `store` and `Provider` in the index file? I'm sorry, I am a little confused.

Comment: Yes yes! So you don't need the Page3 component now. Is that okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153709/discussion-between-somename-and-mustansir-zia).