# undefined is not an object (evaluating _this2.props.navigation.navigate)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm working with react-native and I'm facing a problem with navigators.

The code:

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
   AppRegistry,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View,
} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import loginScreen from './src/components/loginView';
import registerScreen from './src/components/registerView';

const Appmemes = StackNavigator({
   Login: {screen: loginScreen},
   Register: {screen: registerScreen}
});

export default Appmemes;

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Appmemes', () => Appmemes);
```

loginView.js works correctly:

```
.
.
.
  <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <LoginForm/>
  </View>
.
.
.
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, AppRegistry} from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class LoginForm extends Component{
  render() {
      return(
      <View style={styles.container}>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer1}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Entrar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer2} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>

            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Registrarse</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('LoginForm', () => LoginForm);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({...]);
});
```

The error is:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating _this2.props.navigation.navigate)

The error is in `OnPress()` in LoginForm.js

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
```

What could be the cause for this error?

Comment: Este es el sitio en inglés, formula la pregunta en inglés o puedes pasarte al [sitio español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: How are we supposed understand this?

Comment: Didn't understand but I bet you are looking for [THIS](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/with-navigation)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! ...Gerardo muchas gracias por la aclaración, lamento mi equivocación, saludos

Comment: Don't register the login screen, just default export it

Comment: não registre o formulário de login, apenas por padrão, exporta-lo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply. `<LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

The error is occurring because the `LoginFrom` isn't getting loaded directly using the `StackNavigator` and only those components that are directly loaded by the StackNavigator get the `navigation` prop (like `loginScreen` in your case). Any nested components inside `loginScreen` won't receive the `navigation` prop automatically so we need to pass it explicitly to `LoginForm` since it will get passed to `loginScreen.`

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060206/unable-to-use-stacknavigator-in-reactnative/46060695#46060695).

**Sidenote**: I believe you're navigating from inside `loginScreen` to `loginScreen` again using `this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')` as `LoginForm` is inside `loginScreen` itself. So in this case you probably mean to navigate to `Register`. So you should write `this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')`.

Plus, you also don't need `AppRegistry.registerComponent('LoginForm', () => LoginForm);` This is because you only need to register one root component with `AppRegistry`. So, `Appmemes` should only be registered with `AppRegistry` which you're already doing. `LoginForm` will automatically get mounted by `loginScreen` which will, in turn, get mounted by `Appmemes`.

Comment: Mustan bhai .. How do I use your logic in my code below:

`<TouchableOpacity
     onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('NewPage',{id:'5'})}>         
         <FlexCardComp mainId='5' val1='501' val2='502' />
       </TouchableOpacity>`

Comment: Pass down `navigation` prop to all the components you're using inside your screens that need to do `this.props.navigation`. Like I've shown for the `LoginForm` component in your case.

Comment: So will it be `<LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation.navigate('newPage,{id:'5'}')} />` ?

Comment: Try it like this. `<LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Comment: This worked for me, just keep passing those navigation props down.

Comment: @JpersaudCodezit Please upvote the answer if this worked for you!